# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: cordova)'

Tags: javascript, iphone, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am Working On sencha touch. I reset the simulator then app crash and show error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: cordova)'
```

I cant understand what problem is that ?

Comment: It's because you can not set nil object and key in dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set a `nil` object for a key (`cordova`) in a `NSMutableDictionary`. This action is illegal and thus this exception is thrown. Check your object before setting it.